# Configure AngularJS and NodeJS server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello i'm trying to develop a restful api using nodejs and express, and i also want to create a client-side application using angularjs. As explained in  [AngularJS oficial website:](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

"The angular-phonecat project is configured with a simple static web server for hosting the application during development. Start the web server by running:

npm start
This will create a local webserver that is listening to port 8000 on your local machine. You can now browse to the application at:

http://localhost:8000/app/index.html"

So i should run client side app in node web server. but my restful api also run in my node web server. How should i set up node js to be able to run both instances of nodejs at the same time and be able to conect to my restful api from my angularjs application

Comment: you don't need 2 instances of node; you just need to serve the index.html for angular from your existing node instance.  the phonecat sample eventually shows how to create a simple node api, which you already have.

Comment: so if i first started my node server for my restful api, how can i run see my angular app???

Comment: angular is a javascript library that runs in plain HTML.  it doesn't care what the server is, as long as the client can download the HTML file from it.  put the index.html somewhere that your node server can send it to the end user.  it doesn't even need to be named index.html, but that's a common default.

Comment: the phonecat app is an older sample project with it's own example UI and data, I doubt you would need your API if you are exploring that project.

Comment: you definitely do not need the phonecat app for anything other than following it as a sample tutorial.

Comment: Thank you Claies, now my mind is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is structured like angular-phonecat, open your package.json file and find where the `npm start` command is configured (hint: "scripts" > "start") and change the port that http-server is using.

i.e.  "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p **new_port_number**"

Comment: should i make this change for both projects?? run both project in different ports??

Comment: As long as your servers are running on different ports you should be fine. There is nothing special about port 8000.

Comment: If you found the post useful, would you mind marking the answer as correct?